# is it possible to have more than one cell vertically in same row

Tags: javascript, html, css

the title explains it all actually. the context is:

I have a dynamic table. When clicked on a row it creates an extra row below the clicked row to show some extra info about the clicked row. I want it to be able to seperate info I put in it **vertically** without creating another row

it is probably against the fundamentals of tables/rows/cells but I wanted to ask if it's possible.

I have looked up for row/col span but I dont thing they let me append 2 different things to one row vertically

```
 function CreatePhotoList(user, table, new_row, result)
{
    var info_pane = table.insertRow(new_row);
    for (var x=0 ; x<result.photos.length ; x++){
    info_pane.insertCell(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share some code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but maybe something you can work with `colspan` and `rowspan`

Comment: i think you can use colspan and rowspan. see [this Article](http://www.corelangs.com/html/tables/colspan-rowspan.html)

Comment: Nothing worked that I tried but let me put the function here if it's going to help

Comment: You could put two `div`s into your td, those will stack below each other.

Comment: @Sirence I'm assuming that would work with tr too which is more likely to what I want

Comment: why do you care whether it creates another row or not, as long as it displays in the way you want?

Comment: because I delete that one row I created by using it's location. if I create more than one row (which is an unknown number) it will be complicated to delete them since index numbers of already existing rows iterates. Otherwise yes I could create more row to do what I want.

Comment: Could you not just add a class to your deletable rows and use the class count as iterator to delete the ones with the class?

Comment: @Sirence yeah I am doing something like that right now since it seems like it's not possible to do what I want in the question.

Comment: I think that is a lot cleaner and safer than trying to alter the rules for a table so much.

Comment: " I delete that one row I created by using it's location"...can't you add some unique IDs to the rows and use those to delete them? Seems more reliable. Then you don't have to worry about changes to the HTML structure. Or a class on delete-able rows as Sirence suggested would be feasible too.

Comment: Add a table inside that "cell" with two rows, not great but if the other suggestions don't do it, like col span/row span. I would simple add two divs with some css.